# Render multiple elements on map google-map-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-map-react

I have a trouble with rendering multiple elements using [google-map-react](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react). I'm doing everything like in example, with hardcoded element everything is okay, but with elements that I want to render using `map` method like I'm doing it with regular react components I have trouble. 
Here is a [jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/bovewateva/edit?js,output) where you can check it, in the map we should see 3 points, but now we have only the hardcoded one.

Answer (score 1):

In your map function, you have to return your AnyReactComponent.

like this :

```
{Scenes.map(scene => {

      let lat=scene.coordinates[0];
      let lng=scene.coordinates[1];
      let sceneName=scene.name;

      console.log(`Latitude - ${lat}\nLongitude - ${lng}\nSceneName - ${sceneName}`);

      return <AnyReactComponent 
          lat={lat} 
          lng={lng} 
          text={sceneName} 
      />
})}
```